# is there a way to get a random element from an array and also delete it just that single element

Tags: ruby

I want:

```
1.9.3p392 :015 > a=["birds","things","people","people"]
 => ["birds", "things", "people","people"] 
1.9.3p392 :016 > a.sample
 => "people" 
1.9.3p392 :017 > a
 => ["birds", "things","people"] 
1.9.3p392 :018 >
```

but doesn't look like sample supports this. Anything I'm missing in sample's arguments? I'm aware I could I could delete with what is returned but that will delete ALL the members that are that value not just that single instance.

thx

Comment: can it be done via sample as an arg. Seems like it should - more curious than anything

Comment: `Array#sample` does not provide a way to do this. It can be done in a single line but it's not very pretty. `sample = a.delete_at(rand(a.length)) # sample may be birds...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more traditional version I initially suggested which [removes the element by index](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_at). This method mutates the original array, but also preserves order.

```
a = ["birds","things","people","people"]
i = rand(a.size)
# delete_at returns the element removed, or nil
elm = a.delete_at(i)
```

Here is another solution that doesn't have side-effects (it utilizes a [one of the sample-size forms](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-sample)). This approach *changes* the order of the remaining elements and may be "less efficient" for large arrays.

```
a = ["birds","things","people","people"]
elm, *rest = a.sample(a.size)
```

I actually *would not* use the 2nd solution and would manually duplicate the array first if that is what I wanted - after reviewing it, it seems too "clever" and convoluted.

Comment: thx, could you give me like a sentence of what is happening in the sample-size form example?

Comment: @timpone In the first form, the entire array is sampled (which means it is randomly ordered) and then the first element is pulled off into `elm` and the remaining (still randomly ordered) elements are put into an array assigned to `rest`. This is a "splat assignment". Here is a simple version: `elm, *arr = [1,2,3]`; elm -> 1, arr -> [2,3]

Comment: if an outer loop, it looks like this works: `elm, *a = a.sample(a.size)`  thx again

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
a = ["birds","things","people","people"]
a.delete_at(a.find_index(a.sample))
```